# Ionic3 get firebase data too slow to list it

Tags: firebase, angularfire, ionic3

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public navParams : NavParams,
  public modalCtrl:ModalController, private afAuth:AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase:AngularFireDatabase , public fb:FirebaseService) {
    this.getDefaults();
    this.selectedExercise=[];
    console.log("home");
    this.exercises=this.fb.getShoppingItems();
        console.log(this.exercises);
```

at home.ts file, 
at constructor, I get firebase data from firebase provider that I made to show it on list on html. 
but the problem is that I logged it console.log(this.exercises) which is the data that I want to show on list, but it came null.
but after logged null, firebase provider get data from firebase and logged it 
as you can see below.

I think browser should wait until firebase provider get data then should list it.
but don't know how to do it.

[image: Home.ts(right)&& firebase provider(left)]
[image: Log data firebase provider's return value should be on undefined position to list it]

[image: this is how I display on html with data from firebase provider]

Answer (score 1):

**This is the way you should go**

> You need to change your `getShoppingItems` method to return a promise object like this

```
getShoppingItems(){
 return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.db.list("/profile/user_id").subscribe(result =>{
               resolve(result));
            } 
        });
}
```

> Your constructor method should get the result like this

```
constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
public navParams : NavParams,
public modalCtrl:ModalController, 
private afAuth:AngularFireAuth, 
private afDatabase:AngularFireDatabase , 
public fb:FirebaseService) {
    this.getDefaults();
    this.selectedExercise=[];
    console.log("home");

    //get your result like this
    this.fb.getShoppingItems().then(result =>{
        this.exercises = result; 
        console.log(this.exercises);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the async pipe:

```
*ngFor="let item of exercises | async"
```

with

```
exercises = this.afd.list('...');
```